# Read A File in Google Codelab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I was trying to read a file into Google Codelab Notebook, nonetheless, the notebook didn't load the contain of the file.

Even though in jupyter you only use a magic key %%load, Colab runs without any output.

Answer (score 0):

The magic function `load` doesn't work in Google Colab. There is a [documented issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/42) about it. I recommend you to read this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/importing-data-to-google-colab-the-clean-way-5ceef9e9e3c8) to learn how to import data to Google Colab. There are explained options like `files.upload` function and importing from Google Drive.